Prove that, except for the identity function, a holomorphic map of the open unit disk into itself has at most one fixed point in the disk.
Prove that, except for the identity function, a holomorphic map of the open unit disk into itself has at most one fixed point in the disk.
By Schwarz Lemma, if $f$ is the holomorphic map, and $f(0)=0,$ then $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ for all z in the disk. I don't get how to reach the conclusion.

Hints: Let $c,d$ be distinct fixed points of $f$. Define $g=\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ \phi$ where $\phi (z)=\frac  {z+c} {1+\overline c z}$. Then $g(0)=\phi^{-1}c=0$. Since $\phi$ maps the unit disk to itself, it follows that $g$ does the same. Also, $g(\phi^{-1}(d))=\phi^{-1}(d)$. Schwarz Lemma shows that $g$ is the identity. Conclde that $f$ is the identity.

$g(\phi^{-1}(d))=\phi^{-1}(d)$?

@PeterMelech Right, thanks for the correction.

Let $z_{1},z_{2}\in B(0,1)$ be distinct  ,$f\in H({B(0,1)}) 
,f(z_1)=z_1 $, $f(z_2)=z_2$.
Def:$$\phi_{a}(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a}z}$$
Notice that:$$\phi_{z_1}(f(z_2))=\phi_{z_1}(z_2)$$
Using Schwarz-Pick lemma: $f\in$ Aut$(B(0,1))$
In Aut$(B(0,1))$ ,there are only two composition of elements : Rotation transformations and $\phi_a$
Clearly:$f$ has at most one fixed point or f be identity in $B(0,1)$.
